# SWT TrayItem.setImage does not scale properly in Mac status bar

Tags: java, macos, swt, statusbar

On my cross-platform SWT Java application, I'm using TrayItem's setImages() function to set the dock and status bar icon. The icon is a 128x128 transparent PNG. The status and tray icons are appropriately clipped on both Windows and Linux distributions, but on the Mac I have problems that make the status bar icon appear with strange padding on both sides like this:

[image]

It's strange to me that this is working on all other platforms but the Mac. For instance, here is the same status bar icon without the problem on my Linux box:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea how to prevent this extra padding on the Mac?

Comment: Without any code this will be hard to debug. Based on some Googling, it looks like you should be able to do this without any problems.

Comment: Have you tried asking the question on eclipse.platform.swt and searching https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/ for a possible bug?

Comment: How does SWT Snippet 143 - http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet143.java?view=co - look for you?

Comment: Did you try another image format (jpeg, gif)? I could be problem with transparency..

Comment: My code is very similar to that posted in the Snippet #143. I am going to try playing with different formats, but it seems like this might be some kind of bug in SWT.

Comment: Additional info: when using a 64x64 icon in the same format I do not get the padding. I get double the padding with 512x512. Seems to be a problem with scaling the larger images - going to try new formats and see if this can be solved.

Comment: New formats also cause the same problem. I'm thinking this has to be a bug in SWT's calculations of the length of the status bar.

Comment: 32x32 icon is more that enough for any notification area icon. if you say that smaller image sizes work fine, why not make it so?

Comment: The size of the images used in the notification area is 16x16. Can you scale your image to that and try? In my test - on OSX 10.6.7 with SWT 3.6.1.v3655c - that works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem in SWT Cocoa sources.

```
public void setImage (Image image) {
    checkWidget ();
    if (image != null && image.isDisposed ()) error (SWT.ERROR_INVALID_ARGUMENT);
    super.setImage (image);
    double /*float*/ width = 0;
    if (image == null) {
        view.setImage (null);
    } else {
        /*
         * Feature in Cocoa.  If the NSImage object being set into the view is
         * the same NSImage object that is already there then the new image is
         * not taken.  This results in the view's image not changing even if the
         * NSImage object's content has changed since it was last set into the
         * view.  The workaround is to temporarily set the view's image to null
         * so that the new image will then be taken.
         */
        NSImage current = view.image ();
        if (current != null && current.id == image.handle.id) {
            view.setImage (null);
        }
        view.setImage (image.handle);
        if (visible) {
            width = image.handle.size ().width + BORDER;
        }
    }
    item.setLength (width);
}
```

The problem is on the line `width = image.handle.size ().width + BORDER;` which just takes pure size of image (in your case it's 128 px). I didn't found any suitable workaround (I saw you post bug report on SWT bugzilla).

So only way to avoid this bug (for now) is to make your tray image smaller.

Comment: You're right. I submitted a bug report into the SWT team a few days ago and forgot to update this post reflecting this. It's unfortunate that this problem exists because it required an intense rewrite of a large portion of code. See my bug report [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=350751)

Comment: Just a follow-up - they have submitted a patch on the [bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=350751) if you're having the same problem.